# How do i dockerize a sagemath server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, sage

i've been using sagemath for a few weeks now, and i've been experiencing some downtime. i saw that i am able to make my own sagemath server, so what i'm trying to do is that i want to dockerize it but am unable to do so, i've followed the documentation on the github but im unable to run **docker build .** to run the Dockerfile. Is it possible to dockerize a sagemath server?

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
RUN npm install -g requirejs

RUN apk update && apk add git
RUN git clone https://github.com/sagemath/sage.git


#temporarily run nocache flag to speed up the runtime
#install python?
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip
#install gcc
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev
#install bash to process the next few commands
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN /bin/bash -c " \
pushd sage; \
./bootstrap/; \
./configure --enable-download-from-upstream-url/; \
make; \
popd; \
sage/sage -pip install lockfile; \
sage/sage -pip install sockjs-tornado; \
sage/sage -pip install sqlalchemy; \
sage/sage -pip install paramiko; \
"
RUN git clone https://github.com/sagemath/sagecell.git
RUN /bin/bash -c " \
pushd sagecell; \
"
RUN git submodule update --init --recursive \
RUN ../sage/sage -sh -c \
make; \
../sage/sage web_server.py [-p 8888] \
```

The command prompt just exploded me with a bunch of error messages, this is just a small amount of it

```
#13 173.2 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t4f6ko9s/cffi_04531dcfd0fd4757914fa4410902e57d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t4f6ko9s/cffi_04531dcfd0fd4757914fa4410902e57d/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install 
--record /tmp/pip-record-ldckhbb6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.8/cffi Check the logs for full command output.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /bin/bash -c " pushd sage; ./bootstrap/; ./configure --enable-download-from-upstream-url/; make; popd; sage/sage -pip install lockfile; sage/sage -pip install sockjs-tornado; sage/sage -pip install sqlalchemy; sage/sage -pip install paramiko; "]: exit code: 1
```

Comment: What does the logs say?

Comment: how do i check for the log?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37834373/188331)

Comment: this is the part where the error comes in. https://pastebin.com/MN8LYCSH

Comment: this line, line 116, indicates the error: `src/greenlet/greenlet.h:8:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: but i have included the script to install python though, is this not it?, 'RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip'